# How to tell endianness from this output?

Tags: c, pointers, endianness

I'm running this example program and I'm suppossed to be able to tell from the output what machine type it is. I'm certain it's from inspecting one or two values but how should I perform this inspection?

```
/* pointers.c - Test pointers
 * Written 2012 by F Lundevall
 * Copyright abandoned. This file is in the public domain.
 *
 * To make this program work on as many systems as possible,
 * addresses are converted to unsigned long when printed.
 * The 'l' in formatting-codes %ld and %lx means a long operand. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int * ip; /* Declare a pointer to int, a.k.a. int pointer. */
char * cp; /* Pointer to char, a.k.a. char pointer. */

/* Declare fp as a pointer to function, where that function
 * has one parameter of type int and returns an int.
 * Use cdecl to get the syntax right, http://cdecl.org/ */
int ( *fp )( int );

int val1 = 111111;
int val2 = 222222;

int ia[ 17 ]; /* Declare an array of 17 ints, numbered 0 through 16. */
char ca[ 17 ]; /* Declare an array of 17 chars. */

int fun( int parm )
{
  printf( "Function fun called with parameter %d\n", parm );
  return( parm + 1 );
}

/* Main function. */
int main()
{
  printf( "Message PT.01 from pointers.c: Hello, pointy World!\n" );

  /* Do some assignments. */
  ip = &val1;
  cp = &val2; /* The compiler should warn you about this. */
  fp = fun;

  ia[ 0 ] = 11; /* First element. */
  ia[ 1 ] = 17;
  ia[ 2 ] = 3;
  ia[ 16 ] = 58; /* Last element. */

  ca[ 0 ] = 11; /* First element. */
  ca[ 1 ] = 17;
  ca[ 2 ] = 3;
  ca[ 16 ] = 58; /* Last element. */

  printf( "PT.02: val1: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val1, val1, val1 );
  printf( "PT.03: val2: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val2, val2, val2 );
  printf( "PT.04: ip: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &ip, (long) ip, (long) ip );
  printf( "PT.05: Dereference pointer ip and we find: %d \n", *ip );
  printf( "PT.06: cp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &cp, (long) cp, (long) cp );
  printf( "PT.07: Dereference pointer cp and we find: %d \n", *cp );

  *ip = 1234;
  printf( "\nPT.08: Executed *ip = 1234; \n" );
  printf( "PT.09: val1: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val1, val1, val1 );
  printf( "PT.10: ip: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &ip, (long) ip, (long) ip );
  printf( "PT.11: Dereference pointer ip and we find: %d \n", *ip );
  printf( "PT.12: val1: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val1, val1, val1 );

  *cp = 1234; /* The compiler should warn you about this. */
  printf( "\nPT.13: Executed *cp = 1234; \n" );
  printf( "PT.14: val2: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val2, val2, val2 );
  printf( "PT.15: cp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &cp, (long) cp, (long) cp );
  printf( "PT.16: Dereference pointer cp and we find: %d \n", *cp );
  printf( "PT.17: val2: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val2, val2, val2 );

  ip = ia;
  printf( "\nPT.18: Executed ip = ia; \n" );
  printf( "PT.19: ia[0]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ia[0], ia[0], ia[0] );
  printf( "PT.20: ia[1]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ia[1], ia[1], ia[1] );
  printf( "PT.21: ip: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &ip, (long) ip, (long) ip );
  printf( "PT.22: Dereference pointer ip and we find: %d \n", *ip );

  ip = ip + 1; /* add 1 to pointer */
  printf( "\nPT.23: Executed ip = ip + 1; \n" );
  printf( "PT.24: ip: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &ip, (long) ip, (long) ip );
  printf( "PT.25: Dereference pointer ip and we find: %d \n", *ip );

  cp = ca;
  printf( "\nPT.26: Executed cp = ca; \n" );
  printf( "PT.27: ca[0]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ca[0], ca[0], ca[0] );
  printf( "PT.28: ca[1]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ca[1], ca[1], ca[1] );
  printf( "PT.29: cp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &cp, (long) cp, (long) cp );
  printf( "PT.30: Dereference pointer cp and we find: %d \n", *cp );

  cp = cp + 1; /* add 1 to pointer */
  printf( "\nPT.31: Executed cp = cp + 1; \n" );
  printf( "PT.32: cp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &cp, (long) cp, (long) cp );
  printf( "PT.33: Dereference pointer cp and we find: %d \n", *cp );

  ip = ca; /* The compiler should warn you about this. */
  printf( "\nPT.34: Executed ip = ca; \n" );
  printf( "PT.35: ca[0]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ca[0], ca[0], ca[0] );
  printf( "PT.36: ca[1]: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &ca[1], ca[1], ca[1] );
  printf( "PT.37: ip: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &ip, (long) ip, (long) ip );
  printf( "PT.38: Dereference pointer ip and we find: %d \n", *ip );

  cp = ia; /* The compiler should warn you about this. */
  printf( "\nPT.39: Executed cp = ia; \n" );
  printf( "PT.40: cp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &cp, (long) cp, (long) cp );
  printf( "PT.41: Dereference pointer cp and we find: %d \n", *cp );

  printf( "\nPT.42: fp: stored at %lx (hex); value is %ld (dec), %lx (hex)\n",
          (long) &fp, (long) fp, (long) fp );
  printf( "PT.43: Dereference fp and see what happens.\n" );
  val1 = (*fp)(42);
  printf( "PT.44: Executed val1 = (*fp)(42); \n" );
  printf( "PT.45: val1: stored at %lx (hex); value is %d (dec), %x (hex)\n",
          (long) &val1, val1, val1 );

  return( 0 );
}
```

Output

```
Message PT.01 from pointers.c: Hello, pointy World!
PT.02: val1: stored at 21e50 (hex); value is 111111 (dec), 1b207 (hex)
PT.03: val2: stored at 21e54 (hex); value is 222222 (dec), 3640e (hex)
PT.04: ip: stored at 21eb8 (hex); value is 138832 (dec), 21e50 (hex)
PT.05: Dereference pointer ip and we find: 111111
PT.06: cp: stored at 21e6c (hex); value is 138836 (dec), 21e54 (hex)
PT.07: Dereference pointer cp and we find: 0

PT.08: Executed *ip = 1234;
PT.09: val1: stored at 21e50 (hex); value is 1234 (dec), 4d2 (hex)
PT.10: ip: stored at 21eb8 (hex); value is 138832 (dec), 21e50 (hex)
PT.11: Dereference pointer ip and we find: 1234
PT.12: val1: stored at 21e50 (hex); value is 1234 (dec), 4d2 (hex)

PT.13: Executed *cp = 1234;
PT.14: val2: stored at 21e54 (hex); value is -771529714 (dec), d203640e (hex)
PT.15: cp: stored at 21e6c (hex); value is 138836 (dec), 21e54 (hex)
PT.16: Dereference pointer cp and we find: -46
PT.17: val2: stored at 21e54 (hex); value is -771529714 (dec), d203640e (hex)

PT.18: Executed ip = ia;
PT.19: ia[0]: stored at 21e74 (hex); value is 11 (dec), b (hex)
PT.20: ia[1]: stored at 21e78 (hex); value is 17 (dec), 11 (hex)
PT.21: ip: stored at 21eb8 (hex); value is 138868 (dec), 21e74 (hex)
PT.22: Dereference pointer ip and we find: 11

PT.23: Executed ip = ip + 1;
PT.24: ip: stored at 21eb8 (hex); value is 138872 (dec), 21e78 (hex)
PT.25: Dereference pointer ip and we find: 17

PT.26: Executed cp = ca;
PT.27: ca[0]: stored at 21e58 (hex); value is 11 (dec), b (hex)
PT.28: ca[1]: stored at 21e59 (hex); value is 17 (dec), 11 (hex)
PT.29: cp: stored at 21e6c (hex); value is 138840 (dec), 21e58 (hex)
PT.30: Dereference pointer cp and we find: 11

PT.31: Executed cp = cp + 1;
PT.32: cp: stored at 21e6c (hex); value is 138841 (dec), 21e59 (hex)
PT.33: Dereference pointer cp and we find: 17

PT.34: Executed ip = ca;
PT.35: ca[0]: stored at 21e58 (hex); value is 11 (dec), b (hex)
PT.36: ca[1]: stored at 21e59 (hex); value is 17 (dec), 11 (hex)
PT.37: ip: stored at 21eb8 (hex); value is 138840 (dec), 21e58 (hex)
PT.38: Dereference pointer ip and we find: 185664256

PT.39: Executed cp = ia;
PT.40: cp: stored at 21e6c (hex); value is 138868 (dec), 21e74 (hex)
PT.41: Dereference pointer cp and we find: 0

PT.42: fp: stored at 21e70 (hex); value is 69288 (dec), 10ea8 (hex)
PT.43: Dereference fp and see what happens.
Function fun called with parameter 42
PT.44: Executed val1 = (*fp)(42);
PT.45: val1: stored at 21e50 (hex); value is 43 (dec), 2b (hex)
```

Comment: Do you know how [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) works?

Comment: FWIW, "To make this program work on as many systems as possible, addresses are converted to unsigned long when printed" is messed up. Firstly, they *aren't* converted to `unsigned long`, they're converted to `long`. `%lx` takes an `unsigned long` argument. Secondly, there's a formatting code for `void*` pointers, `%p` which can be used to print addresses. Third, `long` can't hold an address on win64, it's too small. Fourth, if you're worried about portability then `int val2 = 222222;` won't work on 16 bit machines.

Comment: @SteveJessop Well, the `%p` is relatively new. For a long time treating them as large integer was what you had to do even though it wasn't really the Right Thing (tm). If the code is old enough it's understandable.

Comment: @dmckee: OK, but the code claims to be written in 2012, and `%p` is in the C89 standard. So it's not understandable ;-) More importantly than whether it's The Right Thing, though, it actually doesn't "work on as many systems as possible" as it claims, since there's a common implementation on which `long` is too small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just

```
unsigned short u = 0xABCD;
if ( *(const char *)&u == 0xAB )
   /*big endian*/;
else
   /*little endian*/;
```

Here's why it works: in big endian architectures, the most significant byte has the lowest address of all bytes in a variable (of primitive type), IOW the most significant byte comes first. In little endian architectures it is the opposite: the least significant byte comes first. This piece of code just checks whether the byte with the lowest address contains the most significant byte of the number or not.

More on endianness [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: If you add some explanation I'll definitely +1

Comment: This does not address the OP's question, which is how to tell, from the program and its output given in the question, the endianness of the machine the program was run on.

Comment: @JimBalter I know, that's why my answer starts with "Why not just". I for one see no point in trying to determine machine endianness with so much code when it can be done far more easily, with the added benefit of being able to make decisions based on endianness during runtime, rather than mere human inspection of produced output. No wonder the OP has a difficulty deciphering the original output; it's obscure. Adding a few `printf`'s to my code can produce a much clearer output.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. It's a homework exercise -- given by an instructor -- to test whether someone understands endianness and what operations demonstrate it. It's *supposed* to be obscure; it's a test! It's not a method to determine endianness, so providing easier methods is completely irrelevant. "Why not just" is completely confused, since the OP isn't being asked to write an endian test, but rather to *understand the code that was given*.

Comment: @JimBalter Looking at OP's profile I'm not that sure if this is homework :)

Comment: @halex Whether or not it is homework, it is certainly a test or exercise, and this "answer" completely misses the boat.

Comment: @JimBalter I see your point. The question however didn't have `homework` tag. If it had, I wouldn't provide an answer as I'm not a huge fan of people posting homework questions on SO, but I digress...

Comment: @JimBalter Let's see what OP has to say. If the OP says it is a homework or test or exercise then I will withdraw my answer.

Comment: Homework tags are obsolete. And the OP's instructor is named as the author of the code. Check the OP's recent questions and you will see others from this course, and even a link to the course: http://www.ict.kth.se/courses/IS1500/2012/nios2io/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can say whether this code is run on a big endian or little endian machine by looking at the output line `PT.07: Dereference pointer cp and we find: 0`. If the dereferenced pointer `cp` is `0` it's a big endian machine and if it's 14 its a little endian.

**Reason:**

`cp` is a pointer to a char and it gets assigned the address of the int variable `val2` which has the value `222222`. If you derefernce `cp` you get the first byte of `val2` which is binary `0000 0000` in big endian but `0000 1110` in little endian.